# colcon build fail due to already built packages in underlay

Tags: git

i intend to build the package named ros2-seminar-examples.git

i git clone https:// git/ros2-seminar.git

and tried colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select ros2-seminar-examples

but it says

> 1.845s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:ignoring unknown package 'ros2-seminar-examples' in --packages-select
> Summary: 0 packages finished [1.52s]

so i colcon build --symlink-install  ( build all )

however i got long message like this

```
> [2.121s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
    'examples_rclpy_minimal_client' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclpy_executors' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'action_tutorials_interfaces' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_client' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_service' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclpy_minimal_service' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'turtlesim' is in: /opt/ros/humble
    'examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher' is in: /opt/ros/humble
If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
    --allow-overriding action_tutorials_interfaces examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server examples_rclcpp_minimal_client examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher examples_rclcpp_minimal_service examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor examples_rclpy_executors examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server examples_rclpy_minimal_client examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher examples_rclpy_minimal_service examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber turtlesim

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
Starting >>> msg_srv_action_interface_example
Starting >>> polygon_base 
Starting >>> action_tutorials_interfaces
Starting >>> cpp_pubsub               
--- stderr: msg_srv_action_interface_example
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/seung/ros2_ws/src/msg_srv_action_interface_example" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
gmake: *** [Makefile:1179: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
---
Failed   <<< msg_srv_action_interface_example [1.04s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< action_tutorials_interfaces [0.86s]
Aborted  <<< polygon_base [0.95s]
Aborted  <<< cpp_pubsub [13.4s]                                

Summary: 0 packages finished [16.3s]
  1 package failed: msg_srv_action_interface_example
  3 packages aborted: action_tutorials_interfaces cpp_pubsub polygon_base
  1 package had stderr output: msg_srv_action_interface_example
  40 packages not processed
```

i saw 'msg_srv_action_interface_example' folder was in src file and also same folder in git cloned file, i removed 'msg_srv_action_interface_example' folder in src. now i get 1 package failed due to cannot find the directory